# What does proto() in ember.js mean?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Could anyone explain what does proto() in this line mean ?
It is from an ember code.

```
Client.Details.proto().set('isAdminUser',win.isAuthenticatedAdmin);
```

Comment: it doesn't mean anything special **in javascript** - probably need to read some ember.js documentation at a guess

Comment: Yeah thats a user defined function on a nested object, nothing really specific about it either, especially considering I would be willing to bet it has little to do with the dunder proto spec in javascript

Answer (score 0):

It is what ember.js uses to initialize its prototype.

You can dig into its [source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/9b9f40f7d4b95a2b19b3f01e7a8391b873746201/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/core_object.js#L62):

```
Class.proto = function() {
    var superclass = Class.superclass;
    if (superclass) { superclass.proto(); }

    if (!wasApplied) {
      wasApplied = true;
      Class.PrototypeMixin.applyPartial(Class.prototype);
      Ember.rewatch(Class.prototype); // setup watch chains if needed.
      hasChains = !!meta(Class.prototype, false).chains; // avoid rewatch
    }

   return this.prototype;
};
```